# how to show hide based on this coding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name_1" value="" class="showimage" />
<div class="icon_1" id="icon"  style="display:none;"></div>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name_2" value="" class="showimage" />
<div class="icon_2" id="icon"  style="display:none;"></div>
```

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Add onclick handler to checkbox w/id checkme

  $('.showimage').click(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    var ret = id.split("_");
    var str1 = ret[1];

    //alert(str1);
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var ret = id.split("_");
    var str2 = ret[1];

    //alert(str2);

    //$(".icon_"+id).show();
    // $("#icon").show();

    if (str1 == str2) {
      alert(str1);
      $(".icon_" + str1).show();
      //exit;
      //alert("hi")
    } else {
      alert("sec");
      $(".icon_" + str1).hide();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

why not hide the else part

Comment: Please edit your post to avoid bleeding eyes.

Comment: could you elaborate whats the issue & also if possible could you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: you can use css `:focus` http://jsfiddle.net/2nrda9yv/

Answer (score 1):

Your question: *why not hide the else part?*

That is because of `$(this)` it refers to the current element which have got the selector's context the event has raised on. So,

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

The above variable has been used two times and both refers to the same object. So in the if condition:

```
if (str1 == str2) {
```

both values are always same and thus `else` never gets executed.

---

Better to use `.focus()/.blur()` events with `.toggle(condition)`:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.showimage').on('focus blur', function(e){
     $(this).next('div').toggle(e.type === "focus")
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name_1" value="" class="showimage" />
<div class="icon_1" id="icon"  style="display:none;">one</div><br>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name_2" value="" class="showimage" />
<div class="icon_2" id="icon"  style="display:none;">two</div>
```

Comment: I hope the above comment have spelling mistake :)

Comment: @Laxmanpalani see the Suresh's comment, may be you would like to edit it and BTW you are welcome as this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```css
input[type="text"] {} input[type="text"] + div {
  display: none;
}
hr {} input[type="text"]:focus + div {
  display: inline-block;
  /* added for style you can also use display:block */
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" id="name_1" value="" class="showimage" />
<div class="icon_1" id="icon">test1</div>
<hr>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name_2" value="" class="showimage" />
<div class="icon_2" id="icon">test2</div>
```